# crypto.dll error 'C_Initialize - This object is not connected to a module.'

Tags: c#, .net, pkcs#11, hsm

I'm getting this error when I try to access. How to access HSM in .NET C# with crypto.dll library?

```
signature.addKeyInfo(new ECertificate(cert.getEncoded()));
var c = HsmManager.getInstance().getSigner("MyPassword", cert);
static Module pkcs11Module = Module.getInstance(@"C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Protect Toolkit 5\Protect Toolkit C SDK\bin\sw\cryptoki.dll");

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static HsmManager getInstance() { 
   pkcs11Module.initialize(null);
   Slot[] slots = pkcs11Module.getSlotList(true);   
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Missing native DLLs?  Does this HSM depend upon a running device driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Solution: HSM device drivers are x86bit. I tried to use x86bit PKCS#11 even client computer is x64. *(I tried x64 before)*

Then imported x86bit libraries to my project and it works!